# Cannot shift to the right because of an invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
shiftrightvalue db 4                     ; initialize shiftrightvalue to 4

section .bss

section .text
    global _start
    _start:
        mov ebx, 1111_1111b             ; copy 255 into ebx
        shr ebx, [shiftrightvalue]      ; shift the number in ebx 4 bits to the right to return the number 15 with the exit system call. ebx serves as the exit return value

    mov eax, 1                          ; specify linux system exit call
    int 80h                             ; execute the sys_call
```

However if I want to assmble this I get the following error:

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

It refers to the shr ebx, [shiftrightvalue] line. If I remove the square brackets its working, although it seems to me that that is also not really "good" code because if I remove the square brackets I get the following message:

```
relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.data'
```

However, if I do a "echo $?" I get 15. Just as I wanted.
What am I doing wrong here or Whats going on here? I just want to shift a value 4 bits to the right and as far as I understand I need to use the brackets [] to get to the value 4 of shiftrightvalue because otherwise I get only the address of the shiftrightvalue and that is not what I want.

Comment: The answer, as often, is in the manual. And frankly, in the error message. It says you can't do that because, surprise surprise, you can't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instruction `SHR r32, m8` doesn't exist. If you want to shift by a variable amount you need to use the `CL` register, as in:

```
mov cl,[shiftrightvalue]
shr ebx,cl
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm stil new to assembly and don't know where to look. I already suspected that it's just going to work the way you said.

Comment: _"don't know where to look"_. [This](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) is the canonical reference (vol 2 is the one you'll be most interested in).